# Starting point for Mobile Device Security particularly in a MDM setting?

Tags: mobile, access-control, android, ios

I am looking for some good reference material (books, blogs, names, etc..) regarding **Mobile Device Security**. I am specifically interested in Corporate **Mobile Device Management** (MDM)  where often companies have to deal with BYO devices. Who are the **topdogs on this topic?**

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Dark Reading](http://www.darkreading.com/). They have quite a few blog entries about this sort of thing and they offer daily and weekly e-mail subscriptions (They'll also sign you up for subscriptions to some of their partner publications). Not all of it on Dark Reading is news, and a bit of it is white papers you have to log in in order to download. Overall they've had some nice exploits and solutions over the years.

[Slashdot Mobile](http://mobile.slashdot.org/) has security topics relating to new tools on the market. It's community fed so sometimes people do not post things that are available in more main stream locations.

Also pick up a subscription to the [2600 Hacker Quarterly](http://www.2600.com/) (available on Kindle also). They have mobile hacks from time to time and give walk-thrus on how they're being done. Also they list exploits and the whys of the vulnerability.